# Store caption into image

Tags: images, metadata, jpeg, png, caption

I am a newbie about the JPEG format, just knowing that it contains some metadata.

1) Is it possible to save, in a metadata field of the JPEG format, a caption for the image with an appropriate length? Does such a field exist?

2) If it isn't, is there another format (PNG, TIFF, ...) which could support this feature?

I am not looking for a customized solution; I am looking for a solution which could be fully compatible with the standard mentioned formats.

Comment: You would have to write the tool, to view this information, if it wasn't standard field.

Answer (score 1):

1) There is an optional comment field in JPEG but generally the EXIF metadata standard is used which is more compatible. Alternatively you can use either IPTC or XMP standards. All of them have description fields. It all depends on what you plan to use it for.

2) TIFF certainly supports metadata as well.

Which you use and how you access it is dependent on the software you use to view/manage the images. And on the OS you are using since some OS's will have tools built in and some won't.

On Windows for example, you can access a subset of EXIF data in Windows Explorer. For example, right-click on a JPEG image, choose properties and view the Details tab. You will see at the top the Title and Subject and a little lower down, the Comments Field amongst others. You can edit the fields here. This is EXIF data and is compatible with many other image tools.